# NodeJS: trouble emitting array inside object to client

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

Trying to keep track of client sockets myself inside of a data object.

```
var clients = {'clients':[]};

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    clients.clients.push(socket);
    io.emit('updateUsers', clients);
});
```

Getting this error: **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.**

I thought that making clients an object rather than an array would solve the call stack error, but guess I was wrong... Not sure what I am overlooking here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put the `socket` object inside the data you want to emit, `clients`

```
clients.clients.push(socket);
```

`socket` object is a complex structure, possibly containing circular references.

The way `io.emit` works is that it first converts the data it needs to send in to JSON string by doing `JSON.stringify(clients)`. Now `JSON.stringify` can't work on objects that may have circular references. So [that's the cause of your error.](http://google.com/search?q=json+stringify+circular+maximum+call+stack)

You shouldn't be putting something as complex as `socket` into the data you want to emit anyways. You should only emit the most important information. If you only wanted to emit `socket.id` you should just push that

```
clients.clients.push({id: socket.id})
```

.. or other such information but keeping it a simple object that can be converted into a JSON string.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Read up on the circular references thing and now it makes sense.  I should be able to just emit socket.id then, and that will fit my needs accordingly. Thank you!